# Generic that works for both comparable and comparator

Tags: java, generics, comparator, comparable

Basically, I have a generic BST that I'd like to work for both `Comparable` objects and objects with an associated `Comparator` class. For example, I'd like the tree to work with `Integers` and also work for `Point2D`, where the points can be sorted by X-direction or Y-direction (for which I have corresponding comparators). I was wondering what the standard way to do this was? I came up with this:

```
public class Test <Data> {
    public <Data extends Comparable> Test() {
        System.out.println("Comparable");
        this.c = null;
    }

    public Test(Comparator<Data> comparator) {
        System.out.println("Comparator");
        this.c = comparator;
    }

    public int compare(Data d1, Data d2) {
        if (c == null) {
            return ((Comparable)d1).compareTo(d2);
        } else {
            return this.c.compare(d1,d2);
        }
    }    

    Comparator<Data> c;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<Integer> test = new Test<Integer>();
        System.out.println(test.compare(1,2));

        Test<Point2D> test2 = new Test<Point2D>(Point2DCompare.Comparators.X);
        System.out.println(test2.compare(new Point2D.Double(1,2),new Point2D.Double(2,2)));
    }    
}
```

where `Point2DCompare.Comparators.X` is a simple comparator that sorts points by their X-coordinate. This seems to work but it's a little ugly. I was wondering if there is a standard way to approach this issue?

**EDIT:** Implementation based on user1676075:

```
public class Test <Data> {
    public <Data extends Comparable> Test() {
        dataComparator = new Comparator<Data>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Data p1,Data p2) {
                return p1.compareTo(p2);
            }
        }; 
    }

    public Test(Comparator<Data> comparator) {
        dataComparator = comparator;
    }

    public final Comparator dataComparator;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test<Integer> test = new Test<Integer>();
        System.out.println(test.dataComparator.compare(1,2));

        Test<Point2D> test2 = new Test<Point2D>(Point2DCompare.Comparators.X);
        System.out.println(test2.dataComparator.compare(new Point2D.Double(1,2),new Point2D.Double(2,2)));
    }    
}
```

**EDIT2:** One problem with the 2nd implementation is that it does not result in a compiler error if a non-comparable `Data` is used without a comparator. For instance:

```
Test<Point2D> test3 = new Test<Point2D>();
System.out.println(test3.dataComparator.compare(new Point2D.Double(1,2),new Point2D.Double(2,2)));
```

results in a run-time error. Would be nice if there was a complete solution for this.

Comment: Another option would probably be to create a Comparator that calls compareTo() if you aren't passed one, but I'm not sure that would be either cleaner or as efficient.  What you have looks fine.

Comment: @Tim I guess I'll stick with this until something more elegant comes along.

Comment: The second one is very wrong. The generic constructor is creating a *new* generic type parameter `Data` which is independent from, and hides the type parameter `Data` from the class. So for example, you can rename that `Data` to `Data2`. It is also unsafe, because the comparator created will be `Comparator<Data2>` with `Data2` being the constructor's own `Data`, which can be anything (since the constructor's signature did not use `Data2` in any parameters); not the class's `Data`. But the variable `dataComparator` must be `Comparator<Data>` with `Data` being the class's `Data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only type-safe way to do it is to have a static factory method for creating the class based on the natural ordering of a comparable, instead of a constructor. The static method will be generic and will only accept types that satisfy the comparable-to-itself constraint:

```
public class Test<Data> {
    Comparator<Data> c;

    public Test(Comparator<Data> comparator) {
        System.out.println("Comparator");
        this.c = comparator;
    }

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Test<T> createWithComparable() {
        System.out.println("Comparable");
        return new Test<T>(new Comparator<T>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(T p1,T p2) {
                return p1.compareTo(p2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a way to enforce type safety between the the comparator and `Data`? As in, you can have `Test<Double> t = new Test(integerComparator)` and for the tests I did, it still compiles.

Comment: @jucestain: You are using the raw type when creating the object. You need to use `new Test<Double>(...)` or, in Java 7+, `new Test<>(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a default Comparator. The behavior of the default comparator is to look and see if the two objects are Comparable. If so compare them, if not, throw an exception. Assign this comparator to an instance variable in your class.

Then you have two choices. Either create the class with an optional Comparator (in which case you replace the default one) and your comparison code just uses whichever comparator is assigned to that instance variable, or your comparison method optionally takes a Comparator and you use the one passed in or your default if none was passed. Which of these approaches to use would depend on how your class is called.

Comment: Could you provide some very basic code so I can see what you mean? I'm a Java newbie. Actually, I'm going to add an edit to the question and then if what I've implemented is what you're suggesting could you just confirm it?

Comment: Can you check the edit when you get a chance and let me know if this is what you meant? I actually like that since it will allow me to use `Collections.sort`, etc.

Comment: this is not entirely type-safe, because two objects may be `Comparable`, but not comparable to each other